# Tortoise SVN: unable to revert

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Simply put: my right-click menus seem to be missing the option to revert to previous revisions.

I'm using version 1.7.5. According to the help file, when I RMB on a revision, I should see:

- Compare with working copy

  Show changes as unified diff

  Compare with previous revision

  Compare and blame with previous revision

  List item

  View revision in webviewer

  View revision for path in webviewer

  Browse repository

  Create branch/tag from revision

  Update item to revision...

  Revert to this revision

  Revert changes from this revision

  Merge revision to...

  Checkout...

  Export...

  Edit author

  Edit log message

  Shoe revision properties

  Copy to clipboard

  Search log messages...

Instead, I get this:

- Show changes as unified diff

  Compare with previous revision

  Save revision to...

  Open

  Open with...

  Blame...

  Browse repository

  Create branch/tag from revision

  Edit author

  Edit log message

  Shoe revision properties

  Copy to clipboard

  Search log messages...

My repository is just in a directory on my own machine; I'm not connecting to a server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The first menu is shown when you start the log dialog from a working copy, i.e. a local path.

The second menu is shown when you start the log dialog from an url, as it happens when you start it from e.g. the repository browser.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely it depends on how you got to the Log Messages dialog.

If you selected the Show Log command from the Repository Browser then you get your second menu (starting with `Show changes as unified diff`).

If you selected the Show Log command from Explorer then you get the first menu (starting with 
`Compare with working copy`).

I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design...

Answer (score 0):

You can configure TortoiseSVN to control which commands appear in your top-level context menu and which appear one level deeper, in the "TortoiseSVN" sub-menu.  Could it be that the commands you want are hiding in there?